# Laravel 5.1 package to read email from Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook and other email accounts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, gmail-api, yahoo-mail, outlook-api

I have noticed that there are some individual packages to fetch email from various email accounts.  Is there one package that will get email from Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook and other email accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php-imap package to fetch emails. Its easy to use.

[Link For Php-Imap](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap)

Comment: Would it allow me to get emails by a label - e.g. Analyst Upgrades

Comment: yes you can check the following link

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/open-mailbox-other-than-inbox-php-imap/